# Can't update to Windows 10 on MacBook Pro due to Apple Broadcom Built-in Bluetooth

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, bluetooth, windows

I've followed the instructions here : https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204990

I have a late 2013 MacBook Pro Retina. Currently running Windows 7 64bit. I've got the latest OS X 10.11 El Capitan, all software updates applied. I've run the Apple Software Update in Windows 7 - all up to date.

When I click on the Get Windows 10 icon, it displays:

> "Unfortunately, this PC is unable to run Windows 10... because one or more things are incompatible.

Viewing the report, it says:

> "The device manufacturers haven't made these devices compatible with Windows 10, so they won't work. Check with the manufacturers for support."
>
> Apple Broadcom Built-in Bluetooth
>
> Apple Inc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going in to Windows Update and it showed Windows 10 as the main update option with a 'Get Started' button. Clicked that and it all worked just fine.

No need to fiddle around any more trying to please the 'Get Windows 10' icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the bluetooth driver using the one found here: http://support.lenovo.com/au/en/downloads/ds031759

It should have the supported Windows 10 driver for the Bluetooth chipset found in that model (BCM20702).

Once completed, try the upgrade again.

Comment: You can also try installing Broadcomm's Generic Bluetooth Software found here: https://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth

Answer (score -1):

Seem like you have to install Windows 10 manually with iso file and bootcamp, then install the driver.